# Enabling gevent debugging in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, gevent, grequests

I want to used the grequests library in a Google Colab notebook, however upon importing it (and patching it using gevent.monkey), the program spits out a random amount of the following warning:

> It seems that the gevent monkey-patching is being used.
> Please set an environment variable with:
> GEVENT_SUPPORT=True
> to enable gevent support in the debugger.

Looking around, the only solution I have found recommended was

`import os; os.environ["GEVENT_SUPPORT"] = "True"`

However, this solution does not work. Has anyone found a workaround for this issue?

My code:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all(thread=False, select=False)

import grequests
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by deleting and importing the module.

Import:

```
pip install grequests

import grequests
```

Deleting:

```
import sys
del sys.modules["grequests"] 
del grequests
del sys.modules["gevent.monkey"]
```

Re-import:

```
import grequests
```

I don't know if this can break anything, since removing libraries is a bad option, but it helped with messages and grequests works fine for me.

Comment: `del sys.modules["gevent.monkey"]` was sufficient for me.